# How to check if a value already exists in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert different jobs into a database and i want to check if there already is an entry for that job in the table. The idea was to use an SQL Statement that returns either true or false depending on the job existing in the table or not.

The connection is propperly established and i can get the values from a column using a SELECT statement as an array by using a similar syntax.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job WHERE key = Pilot";

$result= $db->executeQuery($sql);

if($result == true) {
    // action 1
}
else{
    // action 2
}
```

the result from the `executeQuery($sql)` is a boolean but it always returns `false`, whether the job already exists or not but i was hoping to get `true` when the job exists.

Comment: Have you tried checking for any SQL errors? I think you should put some quotes around the key you are searching for

Comment: `key` is a mysql __reserverd__ word.

Comment: “Pilot” should probably be in quotes too.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE job ADD UNIQUE KEY key_job(key)` (with key quoted), then you don't have a race condition when you insert. If you get a duplicate key error then you can do action 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is invalid, `key` is a reserved word and should be quoted with backticks. Also the parameter you have should be quoted as well:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job WHERE `key` = 'Pilot'";
```